# Cyclical associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I think I'm confusing myself when it comes to this association and getting lost in it's cyclical nature.

I have a user, the user can post many jobs. Therefore I have 2 models with the following associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, :dependent => :delete_all
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, here's where I'm getting a bit confused. A user can also apply to many jobs. How would I add that to the associations? I know it's super simple, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your case user.jobs will point to all the jobs associated with the user(posted jobs + applied jobs). so you have to create two model one pointing to posted jobs and one pointing to applied jobs.. totally depeneds on your table schema..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with following.

User Model

```
has_may :jobs
has_may :job_applies
```

Job Model

```
belong_to :user
has_many :job_applies
```

JobApply

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :job
validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope=>:job_id}
```

I Hope this will help Thanks.

Comment: OK, I used a hybrid of that answer. I don't know why it wasn't computing in my head without the hand-holding. Thanks for that.